# What's going on with my monitor?

Tags: display, desktop-computer

It just appeared out of nowhere while using the pc. As you can see, the screen is not only pink on the left side - but it is also weird looking (I put the Paint window on both sides for the photos, taken with my phone). Left side is weird, right side is ok. I replaced the cable, nothing changed (it also appears when I connect my gaming console instead).

[image: monitor 1]
[image: monitor 2]
[image: monitor 3]

Comment: From its appearance, in the days of CRT displays, I'd have said that it had become magnetized and needed degaussing (easily done). Of course, that doesn't apply to LCD's and OLED's. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Also (in addition to your post), connect the monitor to another regular computer and test.

> nothing changed (it also appears when I connect my gaming console
> instead).

I think you will find the monitor acts up on whatever device you hook it to.

So then it needs to be replaced. Very very few monitors are worth going to a service shop and having them repaired.  Overall economics are against that.

Probably replace the monitor

Comment: the monitor is probably from 2009 or so. I guess it was used enough

Comment: I suggested replacing it in my answer, so you may wish to accept that.